# Possible xorg memory leak

Tags: ubuntu, xorg, kde, memory-leaks, sddm

My problem in one picture :

[image: memory_leak]

The memory usage of xorg as a child process of sddm keeps growing with time.
Everytime I restart my computer, the problem reappears after a few dozens of minutes.

I tried to troubleshoot with the logfile but it seems to be empty. I did not find an answer in the similar questions I did consult (most of them several years old)

Do you have any idea ?

I'm running Kubuntu 18.10.

```
top - 15:17:36 up  1:59,  1 user,  load average: 0,97, 1,07, 1,04
Tasks: 311 total,   1 running, 310 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s):  2,1 us,  1,9 sy,  0,0 ni, 95,6 id,  0,0 wa,  0,0 hi,  0,4 si,  0,0 st
MiB Mem :  15890,9 total,   4239,6 free,   4370,2 used,   7281,1 buff/cache
MiB Swap:   2048,0 total,   2048,0 free,      0,0 used.   7138,1 avail Mem 

  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU  %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND                                                                                                                 
  935 root      20   0 5335156   3,7g   3,5g S   2,0  23,7  12:43.05 Xorg                                                                                                                    
11325 jerome    20   0 1949572 480928 192236 S   9,3   3,0   3:34.33 slack                                                                                                                   
 5344 jerome    20   0 2079560 461944 160196 S   1,0   2,8   3:06.75 Web Content                                                                                                             
 2717 jerome    20   0 2902428 443580 176668 S   8,6   2,7  21:13.66 firefox 

pmap -qx $(pgrep Xorg) 
>> 935:   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg -nolisten tcp -auth /var/run/sddm/{06d4bda6-5612-4561-ac5c-375bd3132074} -background none -noreset -displayfd 17 -seat seat0 vt1

ps -o ppid= -p 935     
>> 933

pmap -qx $(pgrep sddm) 
>> 933:   /usr/bin/sddm
```